# How can I configure intervlan routing using SG300-10, SG300-28MP, SG200-50 and RV042

Tags: cisco, vlan

I need help configuring inter-VLAN routing. I am setting up 2 VLANs plus the admin VLAN 1 as follows:

- RV042 is used as a firewall (i'll probably replace it with something else)

  - LAN ip addr 10.1.1.10
  - SG300-10 connected to VLAN1 port
- SG300-10 is my core switch.

  - VLAN 1 (admin) - 10.1.1.1
  - VLAN 2 (cameras) - 192.168.200.254
  - VLAN 3 (computers and 1 server) - 192.168.100.254
  - ports 8 - 10 trunked
  - GVRP enabled
  - 2 dhcp pool network setup on this switch
  - default route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.1.1.10
- SG300-28MP is my POE camera switch

  - VLAN 2 - 10.1.1.3
  - vlans created automatically through gvrp
  - vlans are replicated automatically from SG300-10, but not the names. Just the VLAN #.
  - ports 27, 28 trunked
- SG200-50 is my computing lan switch

  - VLAN 3 - 10.1.1.2
  - vlans created manually since I could not find anywhere to configure gvrp.
  - The SG200 switch does not support CLI. It is only configurable through the web interface.

I assume gvrp is not supported on this switch.

Please see the attached image file for more details. I am also attaching the configuration files.

Can someone help me figure this out please. At this point in time, I am not able to get the 3 SGx00 to route among each other.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: I can't seem to find a CLI guide for the RV042.  [The admin guide](http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/routers/csbr/rv0xx/administration/guide/rv0xx_AG_78-19576.pdf) also doesn't mention a console.  Without some sort of IOS-like command line with clearly-defined semantics it's going to be pretty difficult to predictably configure that RV042.

Comment: The RV042 does not support a console. It is only web based. I plan to replace it with a linksys RV042 (yes it is the same name, but does not support vlans). If you explain to me the concept of what I need to do, I think that would be of great help. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you with this on the RV042. I'm no expert, but what you're striving for seems sufficiently complex that I wouldn't attempt configuring it from an arcane GUI.  There are too many pitfalls that could easily undermine your network's security.  You might want to consider using a Cisco ASA instead.  ASA has well-defined configuration behavior and thousands or millions of professionals who understand their behavior who could help you.

Comment: Thanks. Your feedback indicates I am headed in the wrong direction. I just wanted to configure 2 simple vlans to keep cameras and computers separate. What I plan to do is rather than having the trunked ports, I'll change the 2 ports on the SG300-10 to mode access and have one port on vlan 2 and the other on 3 and on the switches, i'll have all the ports in access mode and set the ports to their respective vlans. I got rid of gvrp completely. I found it useless anyway.